# ForeignKey not valid error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, foreign-keys

I tried to add a super market to my database and when I click on Create I got a foreign key attribute is no valid error. Please what am I doing wrong?

```
namespace SupermarketDemo.Models
{
    public class Item
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Size { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Market")]
    public long Supermarket_Id { get; set; }

    public Market Supermarket { get; set; }
}

public class Market
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Supermarket_Name { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: What values are you trying to insert?  What key is giving the error?

Answer (score 0):

foreign key attribute must point the foreign key name not type, change it like below:

```
[ForeignKey("Supermarket")]
```

**[UPDATE]**

or you can remove the ForeignKey attribute completely, but you should consider naming rules by adding just Id to the foreign key id like below:

```
public long SupermarketId { get; set; }
public Market Supermarket { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be also you should add virtual to foreign key navigation property:

```
// Navigation property 
public virtual Market Supermarket { get; set; }
```

This link may help you: [Entity Framework Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679962(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: In this link you can see that ForeignKey attribute in not mandatory.